# Google Cloud - resource_manager Python module issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

I am preparing automation for Google Cloud. I am using native Python modules. All my code is stored on a GIT repository. I am using PyCharm, and I added file source in PyCharm in order to use GIT stored files (Settings/Project/Project Structure). I added GIT files as `sources root`. Once I run my code I am still receiving error message like this: `ImportError: cannot import name 'resource_manager' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)`. On my laptop I have installed required modules for Google automation: google-api-python-client, oauth2client, google-cloud-resource-manager. Rest of the modules work fine, I am able to import custom modules. I have installed Python 3.9, pip v. 21.2.2, google-cloud-resource-manager 1.0.2

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following version google-cloud-resource-manager==0.30.0

Comment: still not understand why the pip install google-cloud-resource-manager, not worked out. And why pip install google-cloud-resource-manager==0.30.0 worked. :(

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it needs to be this now:

```
from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3
```